# Using a Windows application from Fedora Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, fedora

When I use Fedora, sometimes I feel the need to run applications installed on Windows 7. I have dual booted Windows and Fedora.

Is there any application that can run a Windows application from Linux? What I want is to directly run an application like the Ovi Suite, installed in Windows, from Linux.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without installing first [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) and then separately installing the application under Wine. The [prognosis for Ovi](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23557) is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here:

1. You can run it as a virtual machine, booting it up directly from the partition.
   There are a lot of guides out there, this for example: http://imrannazar.com/Running-a-Windows-Partition-in-VMware
2. Also, you can import your registry and userspace files from windows into WINE on Linux and try to run the app from the partition.

But both of those are very risky, in case of the first one, you can ruin your windows installation pretty easily. Second one can ruin the app and its' settings.

So I really suggest you to install the application in Linux, using WINE. It would be the safest and the most convenient way to do this.